# compiling and running a single OpenMP source file with several other non-OpenMP source files

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90

I'm trying to compile multiple FORTRAN source files, where I applied some OpenMP directives to one of the source files. For instance :

### The compilation flags :

```
COMPILE00='ifort -O3 -openmp -openmp_report -fpconstant -fp-model precise -fpe0 -traceback -ftrapuv'
COMPILE0='ifort -O3 -fpconstant -fp-model precise -fpe0 -traceback -ftrapuv'
```

### The compiled files :

```
$COMPILE0 -c microprm.F90 modules.F90 
$COMPILE0 -c jernewf3p_A.F90 SMAX.F90 DE_MOTT.F90 twoinitm.F90 helek03.F90 
$COMPILE00 -c helek04.F90 
$COMPILE0 -c jernewf3p_melt.F90 dmin_G.F90 
$COMPILE0 -c submelt_condevap.F90
```

### Linking :

```
$COMPILE00 -o TKE.x *.o -lm
```

So the source code `helek04.F90` has some OpenMP directives. It is being called from `submelt_condevap.F90` which hasn't. 
Is this correct compilation practice ? How should I compile it using the `use omp_lib` module ? Is it code-safe to compile only one file with OpenMP and link all the others with OpenMP ?

The compilation was aborted. When compiling with $COMPILE00 for ALL the files, the simulation runs, but gets a floating point exception, which doesn't occur in the serial code.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of issues that can arise. Unfortunately your description is not detailed enough. I would generally recommend to use `-openmp` for all files, I don't see a reason for making a distinction. Intel Fortran by default does not make the code reentrant and if you call a subroutine that has not been compiled with `-openmp` from the parallel region race conditions can occur. Especially during I/O operations problems are quite likely. If you have some strange reason to avoid `-openmp` you can try `-reentrancy threaded`.

If there are no calls to other code from the parallel part, and it does not run concurrently with the non-parallel part, there shouldn't be issues with it.

It is quite possible you have some race condition or other threading problem in your OpenMP code. Use tools included in your compiler collection to debug them. Intel Inspector XE is a good tool for these kinds of problems. Use options like `-warn -check -g -traceback` to have some useful checks. Valgrind can also be useful.